# How to display JSON data?

Tags: json, flutter, api, dart

How to display `DietName` which is under `Data`? I can display the item which is under `PartnerData[]` But what is the syntax just to display `DietName`?

```
{
    "Status": "1",
    "Message": "",
    "Data": {
        "EncDietId": "pEl2B9kuumKRxIxLJO76eQ==",
        "DietName": "dietcian2",
        "Email": null,
        "Phone": null,
        "AlternatePhone": null,
        "Image": "http://mjjjjctor/65AUEYMCUE8RTD2UKBRV.jpg",
        "Description": null,
        "Fee": null,
        "DiscountedFee": null,
        "BookingFee": null,
        "VisitDay": null,
        "TimeFrom": null,
        "TimeTo": null
    },
    "PartnerData": [
        {
            "PartnerId": "13",
            "EncPartnerId": "65gtodyhbtdInTsJWr1ZkA==",
            "PartnerName": "Rasomoy pvt. Hospital",
            "PartnerAddress": "Kol,Kol,Kol,Wb",
            "Fee": "1200",
            "DiscountedFee": "900",
            "BookingFee": "500",
            "DayList": [
                {
                    "DayName": "Wednesday",
                    "TimeFrom": "10:00",
                    "TimeTo": "16:00"
                },
                {
                    "DayName": "Friday",
                    "TimeFrom": "10:00",
                    "TimeTo": "16:00"
                },
                {
                    "DayName": "Saturday",
                    "TimeFrom": "10:00",
                    "TimeTo": "16:00"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Model class:

```
  DietDetailsModel dietDetailsModelFromJson(String str) => DietDetailsModel.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String dietDetailsModelToJson(DietDetailsModel data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class DietDetailsModel {
    DietDetailsModel({
        required this.status,
        required this.message,
        required this.data,
        required this.partnerData,
    });

    String status;
    String message;
    Data data;
    List<PartnerDatum> partnerData;

    factory DietDetailsModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => DietDetailsModel(
        status: json["Status"],
        message: json["Message"],
        data: Data.fromJson(json["Data"]),
        partnerData: List<PartnerDatum>.from(json["PartnerData"].map((x) => PartnerDatum.fromJson(x))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "Status": status,
        "Message": message,
        "Data": data.toJson(),
        "PartnerData": List<dynamic>.from(partnerData.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    };
}

class Data {
    Data({
        required this.encDietId,
        required this.dietName,
        required this.email,
        required this.phone,
        required this.alternatePhone,
        required this.image,
        required this.description,
        required this.fee,
        required this.discountedFee,
        required this.bookingFee,
        required this.visitDay,
        required this.timeFrom,
        required this.timeTo,
    });

    String encDietId;
    String dietName;
    dynamic email;
    dynamic phone;
    dynamic alternatePhone;
    String image;
    dynamic description;
    dynamic fee;
    dynamic discountedFee;
    dynamic bookingFee;
    dynamic visitDay;
    dynamic timeFrom;
    dynamic timeTo;

    factory Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Data(
        encDietId: json["EncDietId"],
        dietName: json["DietName"],
        email: json["Email"],
        phone: json["Phone"],
        alternatePhone: json["AlternatePhone"],
        image: json["Image"],
        description: json["Description"],
        fee: json["Fee"],
        discountedFee: json["DiscountedFee"],
        bookingFee: json["BookingFee"],
        visitDay: json["VisitDay"],
        timeFrom: json["TimeFrom"],
        timeTo: json["TimeTo"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "EncDietId": encDietId,
        "DietName": dietName,
        "Email": email,
        "Phone": phone,
        "AlternatePhone": alternatePhone,
        "Image": image,
        "Description": description,
        "Fee": fee,
        "DiscountedFee": discountedFee,
        "BookingFee": bookingFee,
        "VisitDay": visitDay,
        "TimeFrom": timeFrom,
        "TimeTo": timeTo,
    };
}
```

My API

```
Future<List<PartnerDatum>> dietcianDetailsApi() async {
var jsonResponse;

  var response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse("http://mjjjjapi/DietDetails"),
      body: ({
        'EncId': encDietcianIdRef,
      }));
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    print("Correct");
    print(response.body);
    jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body.toString());
    print(jsonResponse);
     //Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>AfterSearchPage(rresponse: SearchApiResponse.fromJson(jsonResponse))));
      DietDetailsModel dataModel = dietDetailsModelFromJson(response.body);
    print(dataModel.partnerData.length);
    for (final item in dataModel.partnerData) 
    print(item.partnerName);

    List<PartnerDatum> arrData =dataModel.partnerData;
   // print(arrData[1].partnerName);
    return arrData;

  } else {
    print("Wrong Url");
    print(response.body);
    throw Exception("Faild to fetch");
  }
  //return AllDietician();
```

}

Printing My `PartnerData` items . But How to display `DietName` which is inside `Data`?

```
class DietcianDetailsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  var encDietcianId;
  DietcianDetailsPage(this.encDietcianId);

  @override
  _DietcianDetailsPageState createState() => _DietcianDetailsPageState(this.encDietcianId);
}

class _DietcianDetailsPageState extends State<DietcianDetailsPage> {
  var encDietcianIdRef;// Need to pass is encId as a parameter in dietcianDetails Api
  _DietcianDetailsPageState(this.encDietcianIdRef);

  @override
  void initState() {
    dietcianDetailsApi();
    super.initState();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        var screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    var screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    var blockSizeHorizontal = (screenWidth/100);
    var blockSizeVertical= (screenHeight/100);
    return Scaffold(
       appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0.0,
        flexibleSpace: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.topLeft,
              end: Alignment.topRight,
              colors: [
                Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                Theme.of(context).accentColor
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        title: Center(
          child: Image.asset(
      "assets/images/medbo.png",
      fit: BoxFit.contain,
      height: 52,),
        ),
        //toolbarHeight: 88,
    actions: [
      IconButton(onPressed: () => {}, icon: Icon(Icons.more_vert,size: 0.1,),),
    ],
      ),


      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text(
             
             ""
            ),


            //========================================================================


             Container(
                      height: blockSizeVertical*30,//38
                      //color: Colors.blueAccent,
                      child: FutureBuilder(
                        future: dietcianDetailsApi(),

                        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                          // if (snapshot.connectionState !=ConnectionState.done) {
                          //   return CircularProgressIndicator();
                          // }
                          if (snapshot.hasError) {
                            return Text("Somthing went wrong");
                          }

                          if (snapshot.hasData) {
                            return ListView.builder(
                                 scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                  physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                                shrinkWrap: true,
                                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                                  Container(
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                  ),
                                  width: blockSizeHorizontal*80,
                                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),




                                  child: Stack(children: [
                        Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [


                               Padding(//====================images 
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                              
                            ),
  
                            SizedBox(height: blockSizeVertical*0.5),


                              Text(
                                'PartnerName :  ${snapshot.data[index].partnerName}',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  fontSize: blockSizeHorizontal*3.5,
                                  fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                                  color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                                ),
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is **dietcianDetailsApi** because you return a **List< PartnerDatum>** and this model doesn't contains a **DietName**.

First solution is modify your function (**dietcianDetailsApi**), needs modify the data type that this function return, because the **DietDetailsModel** model contains both variables that you need.

Example:

Inside of **dietcianDetailsApi** you can assign the value, like this:

```
Future<DietDetailsModel> dietcianDetailsApi() async {
var jsonResponse;

  var response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse("http://medbo.digitalicon.in/api/medboapi/DietDetails"),
      body: ({
        'EncId': encDietcianIdRef,
      }));

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body.toString());
    DietDetailsModel dataModel = dietDetailsModelFromJson(response.body);
    
    return dataModel
  } else {
    print("Wrong Url");
    print(response.body);
    throw Exception("Faild to fetch");
  }
```

Finally, you can replace your **FutureBuilder** for this:

```
FutureBuilder(
    future: dietcianDetailsApi(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return Text("Somthing went wrong");
      }

      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        var dietDetails = snapshot.data;
        print('PartnerData: ${dietDetails.partnerData}');
        print('DietName: ${dietDetails.data.dietName}');

        // ADD YOUR CODE
      } 
     }
    ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Future is returning only the `partnerData` while it could as well return the whole `DietDetailsModel` in one object.

If you return the `DietDetailsModel` `dataModel` you could then consume the response in `DietcianDetailsPage`. Your ListView would use dataModel.data.partnerData but you could also access dataModel.data.data.

I hope I did not mix up the fields in your code.